# How can I get a result based on if a number is in a certain range AND in a specific category?

Tags: excel, vba, match, formula, lookup

I have a bunch of rules that I need to categorize my data in. The data set has (1) an identifying number and (2) and category.

The rules need to look at the range that the number is in, in combination with the category to get the resulting final category. The issue I'm having is the some of the ranges overlap

[here is an example of a set of the data with the desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEXFL.png)

[this is an example table of the rules. there is a lower range, upper range, category, and corresponding result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AafH1.png)

My original strategy was to label the ranges and use a lookup to find what range it was in. Then I used a vlookup to search, concatenating the range name with the category. This breaks down when the ranges overlap because some numbers could be in multiple ranges and the difference would just be the category name.

Is there any way to do a complex lookup that looks to see both the range the number is in combined with the second criteria of the category?

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the FILTER formula?

Comment: Are number, low and high values all integer. If so what would the sum of all the high values be.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer for earlier versions of Excel using Aggregate. It's just a pull-down formula:

```
=INDEX(H$1:H$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E$2:E$6)/
((E$2:E$6<=A2)*(F$2:F$6>=A2)*(G$2:G$6=B2)),1))
```

The idea is that it finds the first row which has all 1's on the bottom of the fraction. Other rows produce a divide by zero error which is ignored by Aggregate by putting option 6. If there are no rows that match, it returns an error.

[image]